# What Happens to dependencies of a OSGI bundle of a bundle once its resolved

Tags: java, dependencies, osgi, bundle, osgi-bundle

I have an OSGI Bundle A and Bundle B.
Bundle B is dependent on Bundle A.

Both Bundle B and Bundle A are in active state.

Now I need to understand the impact of below scenarios on Bundle B

1) I have stopped Bundle A, what would happen to Bundle B.

2) I have uninstalled Bundle A. What would happen to Bundle B.

3) I have stopped Bundle A, Then I stopped Bundle B and now I am trying to resolve B from installed state.

4) I have uninstalled Bundle A, Then I stopped Bundle B and now I am trying to resolve B from installed state.

Could anyone please answer this?

I have tried this with apache Felix console and I do not see any impact on B in any of the above scenario.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Best way would be try this out in Apache servicemix using 2 bundles containing test code.

Comment: To clarify, are these intended to be sequential? Or separate scenarios, each one separately following the state described in the first 2 sentences?

Comment: @Shinchan I have tried that but I always see no impact on B in either scenario and I do not have an explanation for that. I am looking for someone to confirm the same.

Comment: @JWoodchuck These are independent separate scenarios. and yes the first two statement would always be true for before each scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The impact should be as follows:

1. Nothing (stopping has nothing to do with resolution)
2. Nothing (B still uses the packages exported by A until you do a `refresh`)
3. Nothing (stopping has nothing to do with resolution)
4. B should not resolve -- unless another bundle is able to provide the packages that B depends on.

**UPDATE**

In the comments, @Ngupta asks "please share some explanation on why B is always resolved even if the bundle it requires is not longer there".

My response: B will **remain** in the resolved state even if you uninstall its dependency. However B will not **transition to** the resolved state if it is missing dependencies.

You can force B to re-resolve (and this re-resolve should fail) by doing a `refresh`, which is an operation you can execute from the Gogo shell. In fact you should **always** do a `refresh` after performing a series of install, update or remove operations.

Comment: I see that this is not happening with me. My B is always resolved (even in the 4th scenario as well).

also could you please share some explanation on why B is always resolved even if the bundle it requires is not longer there.

Comment: You will need to give more information then. What does B's dependency on A look like, how did you uninstall A, exactly what did you do with B after uninstalling A, etc.

Comment: In particular, your description of what you did to B in (4) is unclear. You said "I stopped Bundle B and now I am trying to resolve B from installed state". How did you get B into the INSTALLED state? Merely stopping it will not achieve that because stopping has nothing to do with resolution.

Comment: As to your question: B will always **remain** in the resolved state even if you uninstall its dependency. However B will not **transition to** the resolved state if it is missing dependencies. You can force B to re-resolve (and this re-resolve should fail) by doing a `refresh`.

Comment: In 4th scenario, I stopped my OSGi Bundle and restarted the OSGI container. So my B went into installed state and could not be resolved because of missing dependency.

Comment: @Ngupta Which I think matches up with what I said should happen. Or do you have further questions?